# Any *nix variant withOUT `/bin/cat`?

Tags: shell-script, portability

I'm writing a simple regression test for a tool like `which(1)` and someone pointed out there's no guarantee that there is always `/bin/sh` (AIX seems to have `sh(1)` as `/usr/bin/sh`, for example) and we shouldn't try to use it in the test.

But we can still say there is always `/bin/cat` (not `/usr/bin/cat` or `/opt/gnu/bin/cat` or whatever,) right? If you are aware of any *nix variant withOUT `/bin/cat`, please let me know.

Comment: No, in HP-UX, cat is in `/usr/bin/cat` Besides, WHY ? Why do you want to call binaries from their full path ? Which Unices are you intending to support ? Besides, BSD-based Unices (BSD's, Solaris, macOS) have different userland tools, you must be very careful, here.

Comment: NixOS remarkably breaks all sorts of path assumptions.

Comment: @thrig Cool, I'll give it a try, just to get some fresh air...